# Setting a superscript reg trademark with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to set my button text dynamically. The text has a superscript reg trademark at the end. I'm using the unicode value, but I can't get it to render properly. It renders without superscript.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *storyButton;

[_storyButton setTitle:@"Learn about OneTouch\u00AE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any advice as to where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a font issue. Only a few fonts make the ® appear like a superscript.

Answer (score 1):

Use an attributed string and give the last character an increased baseline offset:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* mas = 
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
        initWithString:@"Learn about OneTouch\u00AE"];
[mas addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName 
            value:@5 // or whatever value you like
            range:NSMakeRange([[mas string] length]-1,1)];
[_storyButton setAttributedTitle:mas forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set like this

```
[_storyButton setTitle:@"Learn about OneTouch\u{00AE}" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is working in swift 4.0 so hopefully work in objective c also.

```
self.storyButton.setTitle("Learn about OneTouch\u{00AE}" , for: .normal)
```

[image]

Comment: `\u{00AE}` is not valid in Objective-C. The OP's code is already correct.